# how to pass a variable from controller scope to factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I want the user to be able to change the cityName used by this service:

```
app.factory("getWeatherJSON", ['$http', function ($http) {
    return $http.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&appid=8c644b89f214d6bee6c2123faabfb05&units=metric`)
        .then(function (data) {
            return data;
        })
        .then(null, function (err) {
            return err;
        });
}]);
```

This is my controller (where the cityName comes from):

```
app.controller("mainController", ["$scope", "getWeatherJSON", function mainController($scope, getWeatherJSON) {
    $scope.cityName = "Rio de Janeiro";
    getWeatherJSON.then(function (data) {
        const weatherData = data.data;
        console.log(weatherData)
    })
}])
```

I tried to use $scope.cityName inside the service without success like this:

```
return $http.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${$scope.cityName}&appid=8c644b89f214d6bee6c2123faabfb05&units=metric`)
```

Comment: Why are you converting the error response to a fulfilled promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option
1. Wrap factory return in another function passing cityName
2. Use $scope.name value as parameter value i.e getWeatherJSON($scope.cityName)

Shortcut method to perform GET request.

**Factory:**
    `app.factory("getWeatherJSON", ['$http', function ($http) {
        return function(cityName){
       return $http.get(https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? q=:cityName&appid=8c644b89f214d6bee6c2123faabfb05&units=metric)

    }
    }]);`

**Controller:**
    `app.controller("mainController", ["$scope", "getWeatherJSON", function mainController($scope, getWeatherJSON) {
        $scope.cityName = "Rio de Janeiro";
        getWeatherJSON($scope.cityName).then(function (data) {
            const weatherData = data.data;
            console.log(weatherData)
        })
    }])`

Comment: Why are you converting the error response to a fulfilled promise?

Comment: Thanks @georgeawg, i have updated my answer , I just reused same code and modified my changes

Comment: thanks @NagaSaiA, but I'm getting error: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

`app.factory("getWeatherJSON", ['$http', function ($http) {
    return function (cityName) {
        $http.get("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+ cytyName+"&appid=8c644b89f214d6bee6c24aa4faabfb05&units=metric")
    }
}]);

app.controller("mainController", ["$scope", "getWeatherJSON", function mainController($scope, getWeatherJSON) {
    $scope.cityName = "London";
    getWeatherJSON($scope.cityName).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    })
}])`

Comment: Thanks buddy. I finally figured it out. Your code is only missing a second return inside the wrap function, just before $http.get